# HSQLDB Backup Query gives COMPRESSED error

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea, backup, hsqldb

To backup HSQLDB catalog in manaual :

BACKUP DATABASE TO directory name BLOCKING [ AS FILES ]

when I apply in calableStatement :

try {

```
cs = conn.prepareCall("BACKUP DATABASE COMPRESSED TO './backup/' BLOCKING ");
cs.execute();
cs.close();
```

} catch (SQLException e) {

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

}

1- If I add COMPRESSED and execute I get SQL exception :

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: COMPRESSED required: TO in statement [BACKUP DATABASE COMPRESSED TO './backup/' BLOCKING ]

2- If I remove COMPRESSED ...the sql query complains that COMPRESSED should be added (attached)...Though zip backup folder gets created .. [image]

NOTE: using jave 8  , HSQLDB 2.4 Server Remote ,IntelliJ IDEA ,database name is ProDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for this command allows the settings only at the end of the statement:

```
BACKUP DATABASE TO <file path> [SCRIPT] {[NOT] COMPRESSED} {[NOT] BLOCKING} [AS FILES]
```

It looks like the suggestion is generated only by IntelliJ.

Please note use of prepareCall is required only for calling procedures and functions. It is better to use prepareStatement for all other executions.

Comment: @fredt...1- You right about the preparedStatement ..thanks ; 2- adding COMPRESSED or NOT COMPRESSED after the <file path> didn't remove the sql complaint before the TO ...I agree with you about intellij... it might be a bug . by the way the backup folder gets created and function well on restore request.